# Prolog List Decision making

Tags: list, prolog

i am new to prologue programming. Please help me make a decision in the list. where when anaklakilaki variable is exists, the suami output is 1/2 not 1/4.

here is my code

here is suami rules, when he doesnt have anaklakilaki his value output is 1/2

```
hitungwaris([],[]).

%Suami tidak punya anak
hitungwaris([suami|L],[Suami|BL]) :-
            Suami is 1/2,
            hitungwaris(L,BL).
```

and when suami have anaklakilaki his values is 1/4

```
%rules suami jika  punya anak
hitungwaris([suami|L],[Suami|BL]) :- 
            Suami is 1/4,
            hitungwaris(L,BL).
```

this rules anaklakilaki, i want when this being excecuted the output of suami be 1/4

```
%rules anak laki-laki kandung jika hanya seorang
hitungwaris([anaklakilaki|L],[AnakLaki|BL]) :-
            AnakLaki is 2/3,
            hitungwaris(L,BL).
```

here my query i ask

```
?-hitungwaris([suami,anaklakilaki],X).
```

here the output

```
X = [0.5, 0.6666666666666666]
X = [0.25, 0.6666666666666666]
```

i want the output is just one is the second output, X = [0.25, 0.6666666666666666] like this
Please help me to perform a decision in a list
Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You want just the answer

```
X = [0.25, 0.6666666666666666].
```

However, you have two rules which apply for the `suami` case:

```
% Husband has no children

hitungwaris([suami|L],[Suami|BL]) :-
            Suami is 1/2,
            hitungwaris(L,BL).

% Husband if you have children

hitungwaris([suami|L],[Suami|BL]) :- 
            Suami is 1/4,
            hitungwaris(L,BL).
```

or equivalently

```
hitungwaris([suami|L],[Suami|BL]) :- 
            (Suami is 1/2 ; Suami is 1/4),
            hitungwaris(L,BL).
```

so Prolog will apply first one, and then the other when `suami` is encountered in the list, leading to two answers.

As you just want one of those, something is missing in your problem specification.